Woocommerce XML Order Export with ACF + Variable Products
I would like to filter out certain orders from my Woocommerce shop that contain relevant simple & variable products (with ACF information) and then export them to my fulfillment partner via XML.
For this I use the plugin “WP ALL EXPORT PRO + ACF”.
My individual XML code works well so far and all relevant orders and all relevant products are filtered. The only problem I'm having is that only the ACF field information for simple products is exported. For variable products, all ACF fields remain empty.
See Screenshot
**marked green - “simple product” “KERAMIKTASSE” and the XML result when exporting, which works perfectly like this
marked pink - “variable product” “T-SHIRT” (in the example T-shirt ordered in size L), which does not work**
HERE IS MY CURRENT CODE IN "WP ALL EXPORT FUNCTION.PHP"
//////XML EDITOR

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<orders>
    <!-- BEGIN LOOP -->
    <order>
        <commission>{Bestell ID}</commission>
        <production>2</production>

        <receiver>
            <line1>{Shipping First Name} {Shipping Last Name}</line1>
            <line2>{Shipping Company}</line2>
            <street>{Shipping Address 1}</street>
            <streetnumber>{Shipping Address 2}</streetnumber>
            <country_code>{Shipping Country}</country_code>
            <zip>{Shipping Postcode}</zip>
            <city>{Shipping City}</city>
            <email>{Customer Account Email Address}</email>

        </receiver> 

        <items> 
            [my_get_order_items({Bestell ID})]
        </items>
    </order>
    <!-- END LOOP -->
</orders>



/////FUNCTION EDITOR

<?php

function my_get_order_items($Bestell_id) {
    // Check if the Bestell ID is valid
    if (!$Bestell_id) {
        return false;
    }
    
    // Fetch the order
    $order = wc_get_order($Bestell_id);
    if (!$order) {
        return false;
    }

    // Initialize the string to store order details
    $order_details = "";

    // Loop through each order item
    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item) {
        // Get the product object
        $product = $item->get_product();

        // Skip if there's no product associated with the item
        if (!$product) 
        { continue; }
        
        
        if (!(
strpos($item->get_name(), 'KERAMIKTASSE') !== false ||
strpos($item->get_name(), 'BAUMWOLLTASCHE') !== false ||
strpos($item->get_name(), 'T-SHIRT') !== false))
{ continue; }
        
        $order_details .= "**LT**item**GT**";
        $order_details .= "**LT**ID**GT**" . $product->get_sku() . "**LT**/ID**GT**";
        $order_details .= "**LT**produktname**GT**" . $item->get_name() . "**LT**/produktname**GT**";
        $order_details .= "**LT**amount**GT**" . $item->get_quantity() . "**LT**/amount**GT**";
        $order_details .= "**LT**upload**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'upload', $product->get_id() ) ) . "**LT**/upload**GT**";
        $order_details .= "**LT**size**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'size', $product->get_id() ) ) . "**LT**/size**GT**";
        $order_details .= "**LT**groesse**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'produktgröße', $product->get_id() ) )  . "**LT**/groesse**GT**";
        $order_details .= "**LT**material**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'material', $product->get_id() ) ) . "**LT**/material**GT**";
        $order_details .= "**LT**print**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'print', $product->get_id() ) ) . "**LT**/print**GT**";
        $order_details .= "**LT**variante**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'variante', $product->get_id() ) ) . "**LT**/variante**GT**";
        $order_details .= "**LT**category**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'category', $product->get_id() ) ) . "**LT**/category**GT**";
        
        //add options to the output
        $order_details .= "**LT**Options**GT**";
            $order_details .= "**LT**Option**GT****LT**ID**GT**" . "1996" . "**LT**/ID**GT****LT**Value**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'value_115', $product->get_id() ) ) . "**LT**/Value**GT****LT**/Option**GT**";
        
            $order_details .= "**LT**Option**GT****LT**ID**GT**" . "2489" . "**LT**/ID**GT****LT**Value**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'value_117', $product->get_id() ) ) . "**LT**/Value**GT****LT**/Option**GT**";
        
            $order_details .= "**LT**Option**GT****LT**ID**GT**" . "2056" . "**LT**/ID**GT****LT**Value**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'value_118', $product->get_id() ) ) . "**LT**/Value**GT****LT**/Option**GT**";
        
        $order_details .= "**LT**/Options**GT**";
        
        $order_details .= "**LT**/item**GT**";
        
    }

    return $order_details;
}

?>


Here are my current settings in ACF and Woocommerce variable product dashboard
ACF FIELD GROUP & VARIABLE PRODUCT WITH ATTRIBUTE
I have already tested codes from posts here and also searched for solutions in other forums. Unfortunately, I have not yet been able to solve the problem - how I can get the corresponding ACF field information (Field Group “DROPSHIPPING DDF DETAILS”) to be displayed for all T-shirt product variants and exported accordingly in my code structure shown above via XML.
ACF Fieldgroup "DROPSHIPPING DDF DETAILS" with relevant Informations
I'm totally stumped on how to find the last piece of the puzzle for my XML code and combine or extend it with my current structure.
Do you have any ideas and can help me?
Many thanks in advance.
Best regards,
Alex
